# Change size of frame for qgis map tip containing text

Tags: qgis, cartography, maptips

I have been trying to increase the size of my maptip frames on MacOS using Safari with limited luck. I have changed the size of the frames but have not been able to display text inside the frames.  My knowledge of html is pretty basic .. about nil.

I have tried:

```
[% "LIGHT_COND"  ||  '\n'  || 'Persons ' ||  "TOTAL_PERS" %]
<iframe width=3000 height = 3000>
</iframe>
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, the maptip box adjusts to the contained text. Could you give an example why you need the box to be much bigger?

Comment: Wouldn't you put your expressions between the <iframe> and </iframe>?

Answer (score 4):

You can set the size of the map tip frame by including your expression inside of `<div>` tag in this way:

```
<div style="width:350;height:200">
[% "LIGHT_COND"  ||  '\n'  || 'Persons ' ||  "TOTAL_PERS" %]
</div>
```

And it's possible to go further with styling like that:

```
<style>
h3 { margin: 0px 0px 10px 10px; }
</style>

<div style="width:350;height:200; background-color: lightgrey">
<h3>A title:</h3>
 [% "LIGHT_COND"  ||  '\n'  || 'Persons ' ||  "TOTAL_PERS" %]
<br>
Other info: [% "LIGHT_COND" %]
<hr>
<h3>And more info:</h3>
[% "TOTAL_PERS" %]
<div>
```

From there you may try to play around with the help of [www.w3school.com](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/default.asp)