# Control size of HTML map tips frame?

Tags: qgis, html, maptips

I am using map tips to display geo-tagged images on QGIS 2.16.3, but I'm running into problems trying to control the overall size of the map tip pop-up frame.

I have followed the advice on other questions (e.g. [Change size of frame for qgis map tip containing text](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/215135/change-size-of-frame-for-qgis-map-tip-containing-text)) but it doesn't solve my problem...

This is what I'm using:

```
<div style="width:400;height:400">
[%CONCAT('<img src="D:/Photos/',"image",'" width="400"></img>')%]
<p>[% "DESCR" %], [% "image" %]</p>
</div>
```

This shows the photo, with text below. However, the 'div' doesn't expand beyond about 400px wide so it limits how large the photo can be displayed - the map tip window then shows scroll bars to view the 'overflow' image and text below (as it does if I set the image size larger than the div, as expected) - I haven't found any documentation suggesting there is a limit to the pop-up map tip, but maybe it exists somewhere?

Before anyone asks why I need a large map tip and it would use up lots of my screen, I know that - I have specific desire to see the images as large as I can rather than just a 'thumbnail', and map tips are a great way of introducing an extra dimension to the map.

As a related follow up (which I can post separately if that helps) - is it possible to change the x,y location of the map-tip pop-up. It looks like it appears below-right of the point that I hover - can it be centre-centre, for example. Obviously when I've got a large pop-up, it would be good to be able to see all of it!

I've also found that if I have another layer that uses a similar map tip, but without the 'div' statement within the same project, it displays as (approx) 100px high and 400px wide. Odd behaviour... I know I can get round that by setting a 'div', but that's not the point!

Answer (score 2):

I've done a little experimentation in this area with QGIS 3.0.0, and that appears to limit the dimensions of the Map Tip frame to exactly half the size of graphics area.

That implies that limit is baked into software, rather than being configurable within the project or layer.

Comment: That's a useful insight, thanks - given the 'un-real estate' of my screen resolution that sounds like it might be the same in previous versions - I will try with different monitors. Being able to configure a project with some specifics for map tips (maybe @variables?) would be a good feature - like being able to over-ride.